# PHP to output values of differnent combinations of numbers added together

Tags: php

I have a product that can have a series of add-ons and I need to calculate the price of the product with any number of the add-ons included.

At the moment there are five add-ons but there could be more in the future. To start with there were only a couple and I was just hard-coding different combinations but now that I'm up to five that approach is becoming unworkable.

A product might have a base price of $10 with the add-ons having different prices so $10 + A + B, $10 + A + B + C, $10 + A + C + D + E and so on.

There also needs to be multipliers of 3x 6x and 12x for each product, so the previous combinations but with the number that is added to being $30 $60 or $120 if the base price of the product is $10.

How would I do this in PHP ideally also removing duplicate values?

Comment: just make sure the calculations are only done in the end, so base price, containers of those additions (don't make calculations on this layer, check for duplicates and whatnot), then finally the sum at the end using the base price and those add ons. these are just words though so you'd need some code for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of treating each add-on as a special case, identify each add-on *generically*. If you are using an object-oriented structure, this would likely look like an `AddOn` interface or base class that would have a method returning its cost and any other attributes that are needed. You would then just start with the base-price price and loop through the multipliers(or 1 if no multiplier). The key part of the solution is using a combination of recursion and iteration to determine all possible permutations of the add-ons.

Something like this:

```php
class AddOn{

    private $price, $description;

    public function __construct(float $price, string $description){
        $this->price=$price;
        $this->description=$description;
    }

    public function getPrice(): float{
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function getDescription(): string{
        return $this->description;
    }

}

class ProductConfiguration{

    private $basePrice, $multiplier, $addOns;

    public function __construct(float $basePrice, int $multiplier, array $addOns){
         $this->basePrice=$basePrice;
         $this->multiplier=$multiplier;
         $this->addOns=$addOns;
    }

    public function getPrice(): float{
        $price=$this->basePrice*$this->multiplier;
        foreach($this->addOns as $addOn)
            $price+=$addOn->getPrice();
        return $price;
    }

    public function getMultiplier(): int{
        return $this->multiplier;
    }

    public function getAddOns(): array{
        return $this->addOns;
    }

}

$basePrice=10;

$addOns=[
    new AddOn(5, "AddOn A"),
    new AddOn(1, "AddOn B"),
    new AddOn(20, "AddOn C")
];
$permutations=[[]]; //Include an empty set as a possible option
//This recursive function accepts the base set of add-ons, a reference to an array to which to add any permutations, and a base parameter that will be used only internally to pass the parent permutations
function getPermutations(array $addOns, array &$permutations, array $base=[]): void{
    //array_unshift removes the first item from the array, since this is done first, it will prevent duplicate combinations that differ only in order
    while(($current=array_shift($addOns))!==null){
        //Combine the parent permutation($base) with the next value in the array to create this permutation
        $permutation=array_merge($base, [$current]);
        $permutations[]=$permutation; //Push to the referenced array
        getPermutations($addOns, $permutations, $permutation); //Recursively compute all permutations that begin with the current one
    } //Subsequent iterations of the while loop will handle each value in the array as the initial value without each other value
}
getPermutations($addOns, $permutations);

$multipliers=[
    1,
    3,
    6,
    12
];
$configurations=[];
foreach($multipliers as $m){
    foreach($permutations as $p){
       $configurations[]=new ProductConfiguration($basePrice, $m, $p);
    }
}
//$configurations now contains the set of (de-duplicated) product configurations(each possible combination)
```

Comment: Accidentally posted before completing. Adding the rest now.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on how `isSelected` is being returned, please?

Comment: Are you calculating all possible combinations up-front or are these calculations being done after the user has selected options? I had assumed the latter, but am now thinking it may be the former. If that is the case, I will revise my answer. Otherwise, `isSelected` would just be based on whether or not the user had chosen that specific add-on so it would depend on other details in your application.

Comment: All possible calculations up front. Every possibe price permutation needs to exist in the page.

Comment: I see. The premise is still similar(define a set of add-ons and iterate), the difference is you'll need a second form of iteration to hit all possibilities. I'll update my answer later today.

Comment: @Tyssen I've updated my answer. The core solution to your original question is the `getPermutations` function. It uses both iteration and recursion to determine all possible combinations of add-ons, independent of the order. I think this is what you were asking. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm having some trouble with it though. I'm getting the following errors: 
*array_merge(): Expected parameter 2 to be an array, int given* (from `$permutation=array_merge($base, $current);`)
*Argument 2 passed to getPermutations() must be of the type array, null given*

Comment: @Tyssen I've updated it. Instead of `$current` it should be `[$current]`. Let me know if there are still issues.

Comment: @Tyssen I noticed another issue. It should be `array_shift` rather than `array_unshift`. I've updated that as well. I didn't test this exact code before posting; I'll make sure it actually works.

Comment: @Tyssen I made one more edit and have now tested the posted code. It should work as expected. Sorry for the confusion; I tested the general algorithm with a simplified example and didn't transfer it accurately.